# Intersect equivalent in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two Queries in MySql

1. `SELECT DISTINCT Game.mID
   FROM Game, SlotGame
   WHERE Game.gID=SlotGame.gID`
2. `SELECT DISTINCT Game.mID
   FROM Game, TableGame
   WHERE Game.gID=TableGame.gID`

I need to intersect the result of these two queries.

Tables as follows:

Game (gID is primary key):
[image: Game Table with gID as Primary Key]
SlotGame:
[image: SlotGame Table with gID as Primary Key]

TableGame:
[image]

My expected answer should be mID: 01
Note: SlotGame and TableGame will have unique values of gID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT G1.mID
  FROM
    (
    SELECT DISTINCT Game.mID
    FROM Game, SlotGame
    WHERE Game.gID=SlotGame.gID
    ) G1
    JOIN
    (
    SELECT DISTINCT Game.mID
    FROM Game, TableGame
    WHERE Game.gID=TableGame.gID
    ) G2
    ON G1.mID = G2.mID
```

Comment: This is the functionally the same as the originally accepted answer, except using old, discouraged implicit join syntax in a confusing mix with explicit joins, two unnecessary subqueries, and no explanation of why it works.

Comment: Thanks..This is what i wanted to in essence

Answer (score 2):

You may join twice through the `Game` table with two different aliases, where the joining condition is equality of `mID`. The premise is that each of the game type tables (Slot,Table) still join against `Game` and return an `mID`.  Combined, they would be a superset of `mID`, but if you perform an `INNER JOIN` on those, any not in common will be discarded from the set. It doesn't matter whether you `SELECT gt.mID` or `SELECT gs.mID` then because the remaining values are the same on both sides of the join.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  gt.mID
FROM
  Game gs
  /* join Game to itself */
  INNER JOIN Game gt ON gs.mID = gt.mID
  /* and join each of the other tables to one of the Game joins */
  INNER JOIN SlotGame ON gs.gID = SlotGame.gID
  INNER JOIN TableGame ON gt.gID = TableGame.gID
```

Here's a sample with your rows: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f57c3d/8

And proof it is extensible with a few more rows: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/afe66e